# Strange Webservice Error

Tags: .net, web-services

Server was unable to process request. ---> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "" ---> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,(none)
 ---> The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.

The calling function gets a stored proc's name and runs it in SQL Server 2008 and returns the results as a dataset, any ideas what I should be looking at to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there are some configuration problems with dependency injection and it is not related with web service as such. If same function is successfuly called from some other application (like web or desktop frontend), you should compare web services web.config with other applications app.config.

And more info could be beneficial. Like web.config for web service and actual code of failing method.